# Can I make Firefox automatically trust self-signed certs for a given hostname/IP/range?

Tags: firefox

I'm working with a Docker container which hosts a website using a new self-signed cert each time it's started. I can tell Firefox to add an exception for the cert each time the cert gets regenerated and I visit the website, but it takes a couple clicks to so and this is a minor annoyance.

I can't change the behavior around the cert generation, so I thought there might be a way to tell Firefox to always trust self-signed certs from this one IP (or hostname, subnet, whatever), or even to disable cert validation completely just for this host. I haven't been able to find anything like that online, so I came here. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Does the cert contain an upper-level cert (a cert of the Intermediate CA or Root CA), an authority which signed the cert (even if not officially trusted), which doesn't change? If so, you could add that Intermediate CA or Root CA cert to `Intermediate Certification Authorities` respectively `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

Comment: @swbbl Unfortunately not, there's no cert chain, it's just a plain self-signed cert so the issuer and subject are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this that works for me. It's not perfect, but it seems good enough and should be much safer than globally disabling cert verification. Here's what I did:

1. Install `mitmproxy`
2. Run `mitmdump --mode reverse:https://<IP assigned to docker container> --set ssl_insecure=true`

That lets me connect to https://<host IP>:8080 and it'll serve up the website, but with the important distinction that mitmproxy uses a fixed root CA which I **can** trust in Firefox. Now when I restart the container and the cert is regenerated, it doesn't matter because mitmproxy ignores the upstream certificate errors and I've set Firefox to trust the mitmproxy root CA.

The only remaining issue was that mitmproxy seems to choose a hostname for the end cert based on the container's hostname, so there was a mismatch between Firefox accessing <host IP> and the hostname in the mitmproxy-generated cert. I'd have to tell Firefox to add an exception for the mismatch each time I restarted mitmproxy and it regenerated the end cert.

I got around that by editing my hosts file to force <container hostname> to resolve to <host IP>, and adding <container hostname> to the `network.trr.excluded-domains` list in about:config so that Firefox would use the IP specified in my hosts file for that domain. Now I can connect to https://<container hostname>:8080 and the hostname in the URI matches the hostname in the cert and everything is happy no matter how many times I restart mitmproxy or the container.

It's a bit of a hack, but it works! I'd still be open to a more elegant solution if anyone can think of one.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

- Run Firefox
- Position to *Settings > Privacy & Security*
- Under Certificates, click "View Certificates..."
- In the Certificate Manager, click the Authorities tab
- Click the Import button to import your certificate
- You might be prompted to set the trust level upon importing the
  certificate. If not, you can do that manually via the 'Edit Trust' button.
- Restart Firefox.

Comment: The problem with this is that the cert is regenerated when I restart the Docker container, so I've got to re-trust the new cert each time I restart the container. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: The CA authority shouldn't change.

Comment: Unfortunately it does since the cert is self-signed; there's no cert chain with a constant root I could trust. It's just a single cert essentially saying "I'm <hostname> and I've signed this cert for <hostname>".

Comment: There are lots of resources to be found for creating one's own CA authority to provide a root certificate. See for example one random source : [How to Create Self-Signed Certificates using OpenSSL](https://devopscube.com/create-self-signed-certificates-openssl/).

Comment: Ah, thanks, but the cert generation inside the container is outside of my control - that would have made this easier. I did find a solution though, a bit of a hack but it works... see my posted answer if interested.

Comment: @harrymc What's the reason for not putting it in 'Your Certificates" ?

Comment: @cassepipe: If the poster could have done it, that means that all certificates generated by the same authority would be acceptable. Unfortunately, it doesn't apply in his case.

Comment: It said _This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can’t be imported into the certificate authority list._

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution is to configure docker so that the container is not required to recreate the certificate. This should work also for basic container setups as long as the container is not working actively against it:

- identify the directory or file that stores the certificate inside the running container, say `<cert-path-in-container>`
- create persistent storage on docker host, e.g. `mkdir -p /var/lib/my-container/cert/`
- on container start, map persistent storage in container `docker run [...] --volume /var/lib/my-container/cert:<cert-path-in-container>`

see also: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/